# Open mulitple project within one window

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I am a new user of phpstorm IDE . So How can I open **multiple projects** in a 
**single window**

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question belongs perhaps at SuperUser or similar. As it is off topic as defined in the help center – [SO Topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: maybe [this](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=phpstorm%20ide%20open%20multiple%20projects%20in%20one%20window) can help you a bit.

Comment: It is off-topic, but the answer is... you can't each 'project' in intellij-based IDEs i.e. phpstorm and so on is independent and cannot share the same instance.

Comment: Why ??? phpstorm IDE is an ide used to develop PHP projects

Comment: While you cannot open multiple projects in the same window .. you can attach files of one project into current project (so you can see and edit them if required). For that just add such folder as [Additional Content Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-content-roots.html?search=content%20root)

Comment: Yes, can be a solution for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open multiple projects in same window, as PhpStorm doesn't allows that. You have to open the projects on new separate window.

Ref: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/opening-multiple-projects.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me the response :)